# What are some good robust loss functions for binary classification using LDA?

Tags: classification, linear, loss-functions, robust, discriminant-analysis

I am doing a project where I use LDA for binary classification. I want to know how it performs when there are outliers. What are some good robust loss functions for binary classification?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of approaches for robust binary classification. But two main approaches that come to my mind for the moment are:

1. weighted likelihoods (see e.g. Muller et al. 2003, Breakdown points of trimmed likelihood estimators and related estimators in generalized linear models, *Journal of Statistical Planning and Inference* **116**, 503-519, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378375802002653)
2. generalised Tsallis loss (Amid and Warmuth, 2017, https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07210)

You will find many other interesting approaches at Huber et al. (2004) *Theory and Applications of Recent Robust Methods*, Springer. https://www.springer.com/la/book/9783764370602
Hope this helps.